# Need to separate the data from one column into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in writing the query for separating the data from one column to multiple column.

Example:

```
Col1
---------------------------
bank.wrong.transaction
bank.wrong.transaction.captured
business.unit.explored.wrong.way
application.failed
```

need to put the data into columns like this:

```
col1      col2           col3
-------------------------------------------------    
wrong     transaction    null
wrong     transaction    captured
unit      explored       wrong
failed    null           null
```

I don't know the length of any string at all.

Please help me with this.

Thanks
Saha..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove and split data into multiple columns in select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735791/remove-and-split-data-into-multiple-columns-in-select-statement)

Comment: Why are you throwing away the `a.` part of the data? Does *all* data have a leading `a.`? If not can you show some other examples and how you want the output to look?

Comment: of course it is best to redesign and get rid of this, you should not be sotring data that way.

Comment: Sorry guys I just modified the example..It looks bit better than previous one..And I am sorry I am not sure how to put those example in good format..Looking to redesign..

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: So the first data point is still eliminated, is that intentional? Is there ever any more than 4 periods in the string? Are these columns in the same table or a different table?

Comment: yes we need to eliminate the first data point..we don't need the first word before the first .(dot)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Is gonna use his famouse `PARSENAME` formula here I think :)

Comment: @JNK am I that predictable? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like the following could be used to get your requested output (cant recall where i robbed the ParseString function from - but i use it all the time, works great)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnParseString
    (
      @Section SMALLINT ,
      @Delimiter CHAR ,
      @Text VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NextPos SMALLINT ,
            @LastPos SMALLINT ,
            @Found SMALLINT

        --#### Uncomment the following 2 lines to emulate PARSENAME functionality
        --IF @Section > 0 
        --    SELECT  @Text = REVERSE(@Text)

        SELECT  @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, 1) ,
                @LastPos = 0 ,
                @Found = 1

        WHILE @NextPos > 0
            AND ABS(@Section) <> @Found 
            SELECT  @LastPos = @NextPos ,
                    @NextPos = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @NextPos + 1) ,
                    @Found = @Found + 1

        RETURN  CASE
            WHEN @Found <> ABS(@Section) OR @Section = 0 THEN NULL
            --#### Uncomment the following lines to emulate PARSENAME functionality
            --WHEN @Section > 0 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END))
            WHEN @Section > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)

            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, @LastPos + 1, CASE WHEN @NextPos = 0 THEN DATALENGTH(@Text) - @LastPos ELSE @NextPos - @LastPos - 1 END)
        END
    END



DECLARE @TestData VARCHAR(255)
SET @TestData = 'business.unit.explored.wrong.way'

SELECT  dbo.fnParseString(2, '.', @TestData) ,
        dbo.fnParseString(3, '.', @TestData) ,
        dbo.fnParseString(4, '.', @TestData) ,
        dbo.fnParseString(5, '.', @TestData) ,
        dbo.fnParseString(6, '.', @TestData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you haven't answered any questions, but I'll show how you can pull the data this way without the overhead of a verbose function if some of my assumptions are correct (e.g. you only care about the middle three values):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(255));

INSERT @x 
SELECT 'bank.wrong.transaction'
UNION ALL SELECT 'bank.wrong.transaction.captured'
UNION ALL SELECT 'business.unit.explored.wrong.way'
UNION ALL SELECT 'application.failed';

WITH x(col1, d) AS
( 
  SELECT col1, SUBSTRING(col1, CHARINDEX('.', col1) + 1, 255) + 
    CASE WHEN LEN(col1) - LEN(REPLACE(col1, '.', '')) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN
     REPLICATE('./', 4-(LEN(col1)-LEN(REPLACE(col1, '.', '')))) ELSE '' END
    FROM @x
)
SELECT orig = col1, 
    col1 = NULLIF(PARSENAME(d, 4), '/'), 
    col2 = NULLIF(PARSENAME(d, 3), '/'),
    col3 = NULLIF(PARSENAME(d, 2), '/')
FROM x;
```

Results:

```
orig                              col1        col2         col3
--------------------------------  ----------  -----------  --------
bank.wrong.transaction            wrong       transaction  NULL
bank.wrong.transaction.captured   wrong       transaction  captured
business.unit.explored.wrong.way  unit        explored     wrong
application.failed                failed      NULL         NULL
```